# LINQ String comparison with NULL handling

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

I am using a LINQ expression like this

```
Attention attention = debtor_response.DebtorEntry
                .Address.AttentionList.Where(p => p.JobTitle.ToLower() == "valuetocheck")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This indeed worked in normal cases. But under some cases it returns an exception

```
 Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source
```

The possible reasons in my thoughts are

JobTitle might be null in some cases

So how can i handle this correctly in the above LINQ and get rid of the exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect `AttentionList` is null, because the [method signature for `Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,               <-------
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

Your error said that a parameter named `source` is null, which matches what [this extension method throws](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> Exception: ArgumentNullException
>   Condition: source or predicate is null.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
Attention attention = debtor_response.DebtorEntry
    .Address
    .AttentionList?.Where(p => p.JobTitle.ToLower() == "valuetocheck")
               // ↑
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Notice the added `?` on line 3?  If `AttentionList` is null, the [Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) will avoid calling `Where`

**How did I come to this conclusion**

You're getting an `ArgumentNullException`, but you only have three function calls:

```
Enumerable.Where          (extension)
Enumerable.FirstOrDefault (extension)
String.ToLower
```

`ToLower` doesn't have any parameters, so it can be ruled out.  And if `JobTitle` were null, you would get a `NullReferenceException`.

Both extension methods have a parameter called `source`.  However, `Where` is called first and can't return a null value to `FirstOrDefault`.  So the culprit must be `Enumerable.Where`.  It's `source` parameter is null, and that parameter is `AttentionList`.